# Properly use SpinnerAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

I'm trying to get my spinneradapter working. I get no error's but
the spinner remains empty. I have read multiple tutorials but they aren't seem to work
very well. I'm trying to turn every row in a specifik color, that's why I need the adapter.
This is my code:

```
public class spinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements
    SpinnerAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> dateArray;

public spinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String>dateArray) {
    super(context, R.layout.ruilen2_spinner);
    this.context = context;
    this.dateArray = dateArray;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public TextView textView2;
}
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = view;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = vi.inflate(R.layout.ruilen2_spinner, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerdate);
        //holder.textView2 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerworkplace);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView.setText(dateArray.get(position));
    return super.getDropDownView(
              position, rowView, parent);
}
}
```

Here's the code snippet where I call the class:

```
s.setAdapter(new spinnerAdapter(getParent(),namen));
```

And last but not least the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinnerdate"     android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinnerworkplace"    android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is displaying but is empty then you might not be creating your dateArray properly. Did you check to make sure `namen` in `s.setAdapter(new spinnerAdapter(getParent(),namen));` has anything in it?

Comment: Nope that's not it. Printed the names of the ArrayList in a loop and they're in it, so it has got to be something else.. but thanks for your help anyway

Comment: I tutorial  just found suggests to override `getView` as well as `getDropDownView` 

`@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
ViewGroup parent) { return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}`

`@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent); }
`